# how to generate public key from windows command prompt

Tags: ssh-keys

I need to generate public key to set up in ssh. How do I do it from windows command prompt? I tried using ssh-keygen -t rsa from c:\ but received a message ssh-keygen is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: http://www.ecora.com/ecora/support/putty/puttygen-x86.exe

Comment: You should finf a native windows command here: http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc772390(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 19):

ssh-keygen isn't a windows executable.
You can use PuttyGen (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) for example to create a key

Comment: Just to be more specific, download the "puttygen.exe" from chill0r's link, Then follow these steps, https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-windows

Comment: See the comment below: starting from Windows 10 there is a full fetured openSSH in C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH

Answer (score 15):

Just download and install openSSH for windows. It is open source, and it makes your cmd ssh ready. A quick google search will give you a tutorial on how to install it, should you need it.

After it is installed you can just go ahead and generate your public key if you want to put in on a server. You generate it by running:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

After that you can just can just press enter, it will automatically assign a name for the key (example: id_rsa.pub)

Comment: Did so, and to change the key from the defaulted "id_rsa", just enter the path as: C:\Users\<user>\.ssh\project1_id_rsa

Answer (score 9):

If you've got `git-bash` installed (which comes with Git, Github for Windows, or Visual Studio 2015), then that includes a Windows version of `ssh-keygen`.

https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Windows 10, there is a full implementation of openSSH, including ssh, scp and sftp in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`. It also is present in Windows Server, at list I can confirm it's present on Windows Server 2022.
So, you do not need a download to go

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```